# Regex: how to match the last dot in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have two example filename strings:

```
jquery.ui.min.js
jquery.ui.min.css
```

What regex can I use to only match the LAST dot?  I don't need anything else, just the final dot.

A little more on what I'm doing.  I'm using PHP's preg_split() function to split the filename into an array.  The function deletes any matches and gives you an array with the elements between splits.  I'm trying to get it to split jquery.ui.min.js into an array that looks like this:

```
array[0] = jquery.ui.min
array[1] = js
```

Comment: Matching the last dot isn't difficult, it'll give you `.` as result. Do you mean "everything after the last dot", i.e. "the extension"?

Comment: I only want the last dot, and nothing else.  I figured out matching the extension using \..[^\.]+$   Now I need to get the dot by itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you'll have a hard time using `preg_split`, `preg_match` should be the better choice.

```
preg_match('/(.*)\.([^.]*)$/', $filename, $matches);
```

Alternatively, have a look at [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).
Or, do it very simply in two lines:

```
$filename = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '.'));
$extension = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);
```

Comment: Cool!  pathinfo() does exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: agreed. There is no reason regex needs to be used for this.

Comment: While have no example on php.net, `pathinfo` works with external url's also. So `pathinfo('http://somehost.com/some/path/some.file')` works too.

Comment: Everyone please **note** the last line of code, `$extension = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);` gives a possibly undesired result when dealing with hidden files such as `.htaccess`. It returns `htaccess` rather than an empty string. `pathinfo('url or path')['extension']` seems to me the better option.

Answer (score 21):

If you're looking to extract the last part of the string, you'd need:

```
\.([^.]*)$
```

if you don't want the `.` or

```
(\.[^.]*)$
```

if you do.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Used it to add _small to a file URL just before the file extension (and any parameters after it).

var prodImg = cartItem.image.replace(/(\.[^.]*)$/, "_small$1");

Answer (score 4):

At face value there is no reason to use regex for this. Here are 2 different methods that use functions optimized for static string parsing:

**Option 1:**

```
$ext = "jquery.ui.min.css";
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$ext));
echo $ext;
```

**Option 2:**

```
$ext = "jquery.ui.min.css";
$ext = pathinfo($ext);
echo $ext['extension'];
```

Comment: pathinfo() seems to be quickest function for this task. Regexp took 4.5, array_pop 4 and pathinfo() 3 relative units of time to do the task.

Comment: **Caution**:`pathinfo()` is locale aware, so for it to parse a path containing multibyte characters correctly, the matching locale must be set using the `setlocale()` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
\.[^.]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I needed to **exclude the last dot** when matching for just the last "part":

```
[^\.]([^.]*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a positive lookahead, I managed this answer:

```
\.(?=\w+$)
```

This answer matches specifically the last dot in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I used this  - give it a try:

```
m/\.([^.\\]+)$/
```